# Create a Rails model relation with external Postgres database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have connected to an external postgres database in my Rails 4.2 app. The database is read-only and I want to create active model relations between the tables. I've made two models Foo and FooBar which correspond to two tables `foos` and `foo_bars` already in the database. I deleted the migration folder because I don't think I need it for this. In the rails console, I can retrieve records just fine:

```
record = Foo.find(1)
```

Then I set up a relation:

```
# models/foo.rb
establish_connection :the_database
has_one :foo_bar 

# models/foo_bar.rb
belongs_to :foo
```

The foos table has an `id` column and the foo_bars table has a `foo_id` foreign key column. In the console:

```
record = Foo.find(1)
record.foo_bar
```

I get the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "foo_bars" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"foo_bars"'::regclas...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I only established connection in the foo model. Once I added the connection to both, it worked.

```
# models/foo.rb
establish_connection :the_database
has_one :foo_bar 

# models/foo_bar.rb
establish_connection :the_database
belongs_to :foo
```